# A single struct has been defined. But it's components have been given two different values and the code still works

Tags: c, embedded, esp8266, freertos

I am new to programming. I am working on an esp8266 using it's RTOS SDK. I am trying to make sense of one of it's example code on GPIO use and GPIO interrupts. So from what I have understood the program uses a struct variable to store the various configuration settings of a particular pin or pins. But the source of my confusion is that a single struct variable has been defined for configuring all the pins and the components of input and output pins have been assigned values on the same variable name. Wouldn't the downstream struct component override the previous struct component? The code works fine and still works fine when I defined two different struct variables for input and output.

Please have a look at the code.

```
gpio_config_t io_conf;
//disable interrupt
io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_DISABLE;
//set as output mode
io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT;
//bit mask of the pins that you want to set,e.g.GPIO15/16
io_conf.pin_bit_mask = GPIO_OUTPUT_PIN_SEL;
//disable pull-down mode
io_conf.pull_down_en = 0;
//disable pull-up mode
io_conf.pull_up_en = 0;
//configure GPIO with the given settings
gpio_config(&io_conf);


//interrupt of rising edge
io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_POSEDGE;
//bit mask of the pins, use GPIO4/5 here
io_conf.pin_bit_mask = GPIO_INPUT_PIN_SEL;
//set as input mode
io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
//enable pull-up mode
io_conf.pull_up_en = 1;
gpio_config(&io_conf);
```

So my confusion is that shouldn't the io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_DISABLE be overridden by io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_POSEDGE and so on?

Here is the complete code. If anybody could help or share some useful link I would be very grateful.

```
/* gpio example

   This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, this
   software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
   CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"

#include "driver/gpio.h"

#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_system.h"

static const char *TAG = "main";

/**
 * Brief:
 * This test code shows how to configure gpio and how to use gpio interrupt.
 *
 * GPIO status:
 * GPIO15: output
 * GPIO16: output
 * GPIO4:  input, pulled up, interrupt from rising edge and falling edge
 * GPIO5:  input, pulled up, interrupt from rising edge.
 *
 * Test:
 * Connect GPIO15 with GPIO4
 * Connect GPIO16 with GPIO5
 * Generate pulses on GPIO15/16, that triggers interrupt on GPIO4/5
 *
 */

#define GPIO_OUTPUT_IO_0    15
#define GPIO_OUTPUT_IO_1    16
#define GPIO_OUTPUT_PIN_SEL  ((1ULL<<GPIO_OUTPUT_IO_0) | (1ULL<<GPIO_OUTPUT_IO_1))
#define GPIO_INPUT_IO_0     4
#define GPIO_INPUT_IO_1     5
#define GPIO_INPUT_PIN_SEL  ((1ULL<<GPIO_INPUT_IO_0) | (1ULL<<GPIO_INPUT_IO_1))

static xQueueHandle gpio_evt_queue = NULL;

static void gpio_isr_handler(void *arg)
{
    uint32_t gpio_num = (uint32_t) arg;
    xQueueSendFromISR(gpio_evt_queue, &gpio_num, NULL);
}

static void gpio_task_example(void *arg)
{
    uint32_t io_num;

    for (;;) {
        if (xQueueReceive(gpio_evt_queue, &io_num, portMAX_DELAY)) {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "GPIO[%d] intr, val: %d\n", io_num, gpio_get_level(io_num));
        }
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    gpio_config_t io_conf;
    //disable interrupt
    io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_DISABLE;
    //set as output mode
    io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT;
    //bit mask of the pins that you want to set,e.g.GPIO15/16
    io_conf.pin_bit_mask = GPIO_OUTPUT_PIN_SEL;
    //disable pull-down mode
    io_conf.pull_down_en = 0;
    //disable pull-up mode
    io_conf.pull_up_en = 0;
    //configure GPIO with the given settings
    gpio_config(&io_conf);

 
    //interrupt of rising edge
    io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_POSEDGE;
    //bit mask of the pins, use GPIO4/5 here
    io_conf.pin_bit_mask = GPIO_INPUT_PIN_SEL;
    //set as input mode
    io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
    //enable pull-up mode
    io_conf.pull_up_en = 1;
    gpio_config(&io_conf);

    //change gpio intrrupt type for one pin
    gpio_set_intr_type(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0, GPIO_INTR_ANYEDGE);

    //create a queue to handle gpio event from isr
    gpio_evt_queue = xQueueCreate(10, sizeof(uint32_t));
    //start gpio task
    xTaskCreate(gpio_task_example, "gpio_task_example", 2048, NULL, 10, NULL);

    //install gpio isr service
    gpio_install_isr_service(0);
    //hook isr handler for specific gpio pin
    gpio_isr_handler_add(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0, gpio_isr_handler, (void *) GPIO_INPUT_IO_0);
    //hook isr handler for specific gpio pin
    gpio_isr_handler_add(GPIO_INPUT_IO_1, gpio_isr_handler, (void *) GPIO_INPUT_IO_1);

    //remove isr handler for gpio number.
    gpio_isr_handler_remove(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0);
    //hook isr handler for specific gpio pin again
    gpio_isr_handler_add(GPIO_INPUT_IO_0, gpio_isr_handler, (void *) GPIO_INPUT_IO_0);

    int cnt = 0;

    while (1) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "cnt: %d\n", cnt++);
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
        gpio_set_level(GPIO_OUTPUT_IO_0, cnt % 2);
        gpio_set_level(GPIO_OUTPUT_IO_1, cnt % 2);
    }
}
```

Please if anybody could help me make sense of this whole code also. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The struct serves only as input to `gpio_config`, probably different (combinations of) fields are used for different types. Based on the values in the struct, the configuration is updated by copying the appropriate data from the struct. When you change the fields of the local struct, it affects only the next call to `gpio_config`, not the configuration itself.

Comment: Ahhh...it makes sense now. Thank you so much!!!. But how does the `io_conf.pin_bit_mask = GPIO_OUTPUT_PIN_SEL; ` work? Is this what tells the mcu which pin is configured and how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `gpio_config`, only with the pattern to use a struct. The documentation should tell you what it means exactly. Apparantly, the config uses the same struct for setting and querying the config. [Here](https://ideone.com/fVN1UM)'s a small (and contrived) example that shows how fg, gb and highlight color can be set and queried.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, stop writing pointless comments along the line of `//disable pull-up mode` `io_conf.pull_up_en = 0;` when the code already speaks for itself. And write comments to the right side of the code, preferably indented. As it stands, the comments make the code much harder to read and add very little value.

Comment: I didn't right this code. It's an example code. But will keep this tip in mind once I start writing my own piece of code.